# Get Width/Height of img Loaded by JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the Width and Height of a `img` tag, when it's replaced by javascript.

I tried using jQuery's `width()` / `height()` but always return the values of the cached image, and not the ones of the new image.

I need that because i have a function to scale the background-size of a div depending on size of the image loaded.

I searched a lot on google and here but can't find a solution.

Comment: could you share what you have done so far, a fiddle?

Comment: @Ani I have edited my post with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the dimension of image try this :

```js
var currentImage = $("img"); // get image element
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    var width = this.width;
    var height = this.height;
}
img.src = currentImage.attr('src');
```